# Get the max value and count using kotlin-exposed

Tags: sql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

I want to simulate this query using kotlin exposed framework:

```
SELECT MIN(created) as oldest_created, COUNT(*) as count FROM my_table
```

How to achieve that?